# Datagridview Combobox value

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, combobox, nullreferenceexception

I have a datagridview inside a groupbox on a form application. I have made this code.

```
private bool checkrow(DataGridViewRow testrow)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < testrow.Cells.Count; i++)
    {
        if (testrow.Cells[i].Value != null)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(testrow.Cells[i].Value.ToString());
            if (testrow.Cells[i].Value.ToString() != string.Empty)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(testrow.Cells[i].Value.ToString());
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}

private void toolStripButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (checkrow(dgvTimeTracker.CurrentRow) == true)
    {
        string cbtext = dgvTimeTracker.Rows[dgvTimeTracker.SelectedCells[0].RowIndex].Cells[1].Value.ToString();
        MessageBox.Show(cbtext);

        string[] newrow = new string[] { DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString(), cbtext, DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString(), "", "", "" };
    }    
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Error!");
    }    
}
```

If I run this code on a new project it runs perfectly. But if I run it in my other project it only returns the "error" message , or nullreference exception when getting the value of the combobox item {1} column of the datagridview

Can anyone help me please??

Comment: It would help if you posted code with consistent indenting.  You're just making it harder for people to help you if your code is hard to read.

Answer (score 0):

If you see the "Error!" message then that means that `checkrow` is returning `false`, which means that every cell in the row does not contain `null` or an empty string.  If you're looking for "empty" cells, should you maybe be testing for `DBNull.Value` as well or instead?  That's what you'll get if you retrieve data containing NULLs from a database.